# how to get whatsapp location data into react native application

Tags: react-native, react-map-gl

hello everyone i am working on a react native application i want to know how can i get the whatsapp location data into my app like if someone send me location on whatsapp when i'll click on that location it will show me open with list of application how can i add my application into that list you can see the below ref image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKHWJ.jpg)

I've added the location permission to my application already but still not showing

i want to get the map lang and lat data into my application so i can store that

Answer (score 0):

For Android you can use intent filter for location https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#Maps

```xml
<activity ...>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="geo" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```